# GraphqlWS setting a cookie before establishing the websocket connection

Tags: javascript, node.js, graphql, graphql-js

Upon request I'm working on a scraping application that lightly scrapes a external website that makes use of graphql and the `graphql-ws` package (so graphql over a websocket). I've never used any sort of graphql before.

The site I'm trying to gain access to makes use of a session cookie to authenticate users. Now I'm trying to simulate this in my NodeJS application. I just can't find a way of setting a cookie for the initial http request for opening the socket. Below is the code I currently have.

**Code**

```
import { createClient } from 'graphql-ws';
import WebSocket from 'ws';

const client = createClient({
  url: 'wss://target.io/graphql',
  webSocketImpl: WebSocket,
  on: {
    connected: (socket) => {
      console.log("Connected!");
    },
  },
});

(async () => {
  // Create subscription
})();
```

This in itself works fine, as long as I don't need to use any authenticated subscriptions. How can I make it so a session cookie is set before establishing a connection?